# JavaScript Inline Validation not Working

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm trying Javascript inline form validation for the first time. I borrowed the code from another website and have done everything suggested to get it correct but it's still not working. It's supposed to turn the form box red if info is wrong and print a message underneath the incorrect box and turn it green if the info entered is correct. Please help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Request Info</title>
<link href="bnb stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:400,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style type="text/css">

.sidebar1 {
    float: right;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #9CBEEF;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>

  <script>
  //Script validation coding borrowed from Philip Brown on Culttt.com

//culttt.com/2012/08/08/really-simple-inline-javascript-validation/

//Validation

    function validateName(x){
      // Validation rule
      var re = /[A-Za-z -']$/;
      // Check input
      if(re.test(document.getElementById(x).value)){
        // Style green
        document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#ccffcc';
        // Hide error prompt
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "none";
        return true;
      }else{
        // Style red
        document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#e35152';
        // Show error prompt
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "block";
        return false; 
      }
    }

    function validateName(lname){
      // Validation rule
      var re = /[A-Za-z -']$/;
      // Check input
      if(re.test(document.getElementById(lname).value)){
        // Style green
        document.getElementById(lname).style.background ='#ccffcc';
        // Hide error prompt
        document.getElementById(lname + 'Error').style.display = "none";
        return true;
      }else{
        // Style red
        document.getElementById(lname).style.background ='#e35152';
        // Show error prompt
        document.getElementById(lname + 'Error').style.display = "block";
        return false; 
      }
    }

    // Validate email
    function validateEmail(email){ 
      var re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
      if(re.test(document.getElementById(email).value)){
        document.getElementById('email').style.background ='#ccffcc';
        document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "none";
        return true;
      }else{
        document.getElementById('email').style.background ='#e35152';
        return false;
      }
    }

//Validate phone    
       function validatePhone(phone){
      // Validation rule
      var re = /[0-9-']$/;
      // Check input
      if(re.test(document.getElementById(phone).value)){
        // Style green
        document.getElementById(phone).style.background ='#ccffcc';

        //Validate Comments
           function validateComment(x){
      // Validation rule
      var re = /[A-Za-z -']$/;
      // Check input
      if(re.test(document.getElementById(comment).value)){
        // Style green
        document.getElementById(comment).style.background ='#ccffcc';
        // Hide error prompt
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "none";
        return true;
      }else{
        // Style red
        document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#e35152';
        // Show error prompt
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "block";
        return false; 
      }
    }
        // Hide error prompt
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "none";
        return true;
      }else{
        // Style red
        document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#e35152';
        // Show error prompt
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "block";
        return false; 
      }
    }
    // Validate Select boxes
    function validateCheckbox(terms){
      if(document.getElementById(terms).checked){
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }   
    function validateForm(){
      // Set error catcher
      var error = 0;
      // Check name
      if(!validateName('name')){
        document.getElementById('nameError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
      }

      //Validate last name
       if(!validateName('lname')){
        document.getElementById('nameError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
      }

      //Validate phone
      if(!validatePhone('phone')){
        document.getElementById('phoneError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
      }
      // Validate email
      if(!validateEmail(document.getElementById('email').value)){
        document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
      }

     //Validate message
     if(!validateComment('comment')){
        document.getElementById('commentError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
      } 

//Validate Checkbox
      if(!validateCheckbox('terms')){
        document.getElementById('termsError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
      }
      // Don't submit form if there are errors
      if(error > 0){
        return false;
      }
    }     
  </script>


</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><a href="Request Info.html"><img src="images/logo 3.png" alt="Insert Logo Here" name="Insert_logo" width="980" height="200" id="Insert_logo" style="background-color: #9cbeef; display:block;" /></a>
    </div>

   <div id="navcontainer">
<ul id="navlist1">
<li id="active1"><a href="Home.html" id="current">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Host Services.html">Host</a></li>
<li><a href="Guest Services.html">Guest</a></li>
<li><a href="About Us.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="Request Info.html">Request Info</a></li>
</ul>
</div> </div>


  <div class="content">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
     <form action="Request Info2.html" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

    <fieldset>
    <legend>Required Information</legend>
 <table cellpadding="3">

      <tr><td><label for="name"><strong>First Name:</strong></label></td><td>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="30" onblur="validateName(name)" placeholder="Johnny"/>
      <span id="fnameError" style="display: none;">You can only use alphabetic characters, hyphens and apostrophes</span></td></tr>

      <tr><td><label for="lname"><strong>Last Name:</strong></label></td><td>
      <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" maxlength="30" onblur="validateName(lname)" placeholder="Smith"/>
      <span id="lnameError" style="display: none;">You can only use alphabetic characters, hyphens and apostrophes</span></td></tr>

      <tr><td><label for="email"><strong>Email:</strong></label></td><td>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="75" onblur="validateEmail(email)" placeholder="johndoe@email.com"/>
      <span id="emailError" style="display: none;">You can must enter a valid email address</span></td></tr>

      <tr><td><label for="phone"><strong>Phone:</strong></label></td><td>

      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"   maxlength="11" onblur="validatePhone(phone)" placeholder="303-777-7777"/>
      <span id="phoneError" style="display: none;">You can only use numbers</span></td></tr>

     <tr><td><strong><label for="comment">Comments:</strong></label>
      </td><td>
<textarea input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" textarea rows="10" cols="30"maxlength="500" >
 </textarea> 
      <span class="validateComment" id="commentError" style="display: none;">Please leave us your comments</span></td></tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset style="text-align: center" >
      <label ="terms"><strong>Terms and Conditions</strong></label><br>

       <p>Please read our <a href="Privacy.html">Privacy Policy </a>before submitting. We will always protect your privacy. You have the ability to change, update or terminate your information on the site at anytime you choose. B-n-B Concierges also reserves the right to remove any person from the site at their discretion. </p>
    <br/>
    I confirm that I agree with terms & conditions

          <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="accept" value="accept" maxlength="10" onblur="validateCheckbox(terms)" />
<span class="validateError" id="termsError" style="display: none;">You need to accept our terms and conditions</span>
    </fieldset>   
    <fieldset>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>   
  </form>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="footer">
    <p><div id="navcontainer">
<ul id="navlist2">
<li id="active2"><a href="Policies.html" >Conditions</a></li>
<li><a href="Privacy.html">Privacy</a></li>
<li><a href="Registration.html">Sign Up</a></li>
<li><a href="#">© 2014 Heidi Medina</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 functions `validateName` defined?

Comment: Instead of trying to get this mess to work, why not give the jquery validation plugin a try?   http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: Missed that U_Mulder, I will correct that. As far as the Jquery question. This mess is a school assigned and must be done a certain way, which is the harder way of doing things. So currently I must do it this way and cannot use the much easier method of JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user3446663:

The following code works.  Note that I have left the form action property empty because you had a space in the name of the form you were referring to (Request Info2.html).  You'll want to either put an underscore in that file name so it reads 'Request_Info2.html' or remove the space so it reads 'RequestInfo2.html' in order to have the file name be recognized properly.  Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Request Info</title>

    <link href="bnb stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:400,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <style type="text/css">

    .sidebar1 {
        float: right;
        width: 180px;
        background-color: #9CBEEF;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    </style>

    <script>
        //Script validation coding borrowed from Philip Brown on Culttt.com
        //culttt.com/2012/08/08/really-simple-inline-javascript-validation/

        // Validate first/last name
        function validateName(name){

            // Validation rule
            var re = /[A-Za-z -']$/;

            // Check input
            if (re.test(document.getElementById(name).value)){

                // Style green
                document.getElementById(name).style.background ='#ccffcc';

                // Hide error prompt
                document.getElementById(name + 'Error').style.display = "none";

                return true;

            } else {

                // Style red
                document.getElementById(name).style.background ='#e35152';

                // Show error prompt
                document.getElementById(name + 'Error').style.display = "block";

                return false; 
            }
        }

        // Validate email
        function validateEmail(email){ 
            var re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
            if (re.test(document.getElementById(email).value)){
                document.getElementById(email).style.background ='#ccffcc';
                document.getElementById(email + 'Error').style.display = "none";
                return true;
            } else {
                document.getElementById(email).style.background ='#e35152';
                document.getElementById(email + 'Error').style.display = "block";
                return false;
            }
        }

        //Validate Comments
        function validateComment(comment){      
            var re = /[A-Za-z -']$/;
            if (re.test(document.getElementById(comment).value)){
                document.getElementById(comment).style.background ='#ccffcc';
                document.getElementById(comment + 'Error').style.display = "none";
                return true;
            } else {
                document.getElementById(comment).style.background ='#e35152';
                document.getElementById(comment + 'Error').style.display = "block";
                return false; 
            }
        }

        //Validate phone    
        function validatePhone(phone){      
            var re = /[0-9-']$/;        
            if(re.test(document.getElementById(phone).value)){      
                document.getElementById(phone).style.background ='#ccffcc';     
                document.getElementById(phone + 'Error').style.display = "none";
                return true;
            } else {        
                document.getElementById(phone).style.background ='#e35152';     
                document.getElementById(phone + 'Error').style.display = "block";
                return false; 
            }
        }

        // Validate checkbox
        function validateCheckbox(terms){
            if(document.getElementById(terms).checked){
                document.getElementById(terms + 'Error').style.display = "none";
                return true;
            } else {                
                document.getElementById(terms + 'Error').style.display = "block";
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Validate Form
        function validateForm(){            

            // Set error catcher
            var error = 0;

            // Validate first name
            if (!validateName('fname')){
                document.getElementById('fnameError').style.display = "block";
                error++;
            }

            //Validate last name
            if (!validateName('lname')){
                document.getElementById('lnameError').style.display = "block";
                error++;
            }

            //Validate phone
            if (!validatePhone('phone')){
                document.getElementById('phoneError').style.display = "block";
                error++;
            }
            // Validate email
            if (!validateEmail('email')){
                document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "block";
                error++;
            }

            //Validate message
            if (!validateComment('comment')){
                document.getElementById('commentError').style.display = "block";
                error++;
            } 

            //Validate checkbox
            if (!validateCheckbox('terms')){
                document.getElementById('termsError').style.display = "block";
                error++;
            }

            // Don't submit form if there are errors
            if (error > 0){
                return false;
            }

        }     
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <a href="Request Info.html">
                <img src="images/logo 3.png" alt="Insert Logo Here" name="Insert_logo" width="980" height="200" id="Insert_logo" style="background-color: #9cbeef; display:block;" />
            </a>
        </div>

        <div id="navcontainer">
            <ul id="navlist1">
                <li id="active1"><a href="Home.html" id="current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Host Services.html">Host</a></li>
                <li><a href="Guest Services.html">Guest</a></li>
                <li><a href="About Us.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="Request Info.html">Request Info</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">

        <h1>Contact</h1>

        <form action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Required Information</legend>
                <table cellpadding="3">
                    <tr><td><label for="name"><strong>First Name:</strong></label></td><td>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" maxlength="30" onblur="validateName(name)" placeholder="Johnny"/>
                    <span id="fnameError" style="display: none;">You can only use alphabetic characters, hyphens and apostrophes</span></td></tr>

                    <tr><td><label for="lname"><strong>Last Name:</strong></label></td><td>
                    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" maxlength="30" onblur="validateName(name)" placeholder="Smith"/>
                    <span id="lnameError" style="display: none;">You can only use alphabetic characters, hyphens and apostrophes</span></td></tr>

                    <tr><td><label for="email"><strong>Email:</strong></label></td><td>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="75" onblur="validateEmail(name)" placeholder="johndoe@email.com"/>
                    <span id="emailError" style="display: none;">You can must enter a valid email address</span></td></tr>

                    <tr><td><label for="phone"><strong>Phone:</strong></label></td><td>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"   maxlength="11" onblur="validatePhone(name)" placeholder="303-777-7777"/>
                    <span id="phoneError" style="display: none;">You can only use numbers</span></td></tr>

                    <tr><td><strong><label for="comment">Comments:</strong></label></td><td>
                    <textarea input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" textarea rows="10" cols="30"maxlength="500" onblur="validateComment(name)" ></textarea> 
                    <span class="validateComment" id="commentError" style="display: none;">Please leave us your comments</span></td></tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset style="text-align: center" >
                <label ="terms"><strong>Terms and Conditions</strong></label><br>
                <p>Please read our <a href="Privacy.html">Privacy Policy </a>before submitting. We will always protect your privacy.
                   You have the ability to change, update or terminate your information on the site at anytime you choose. B-n-B
                   Concierges also reserves the right to remove any person from the site at their discretion.</p><br/>
                   I confirm that I agree with terms & conditions

                <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" value="accept" maxlength="10" onblur="validateCheckbox(name)" />
                <span class="validateError" id="termsError" style="display: none;">You need to accept our terms and conditions</span>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            </fieldset>   
        </form>

    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div id="navcontainer">
            <ul id="navlist2">
                <li id="active2"><a href="Policies.html" >Conditions</a></li>
                <li><a href="Privacy.html">Privacy</a></li>
                <li><a href="Registration.html">Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">© 2014 Heidi Medina</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Trevor. It worked! I've been staring at that code for 3 days trying to find the errors. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome!  Comparing what you had before to the new code will show you where you might have been going wrong.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this warrants an answer, but I do not have enough reputation to comment as of yet.

Consider using HTML5 patterns if possible.
**Examples**:
http://html5pattern.com/Names
**Polyfill**:
https://github.com/ryanseddon/H5F

Most of the time simply specifying the input type is enough (phone, email)
    `<input type="email" name="" value="" required />`

You can fine-tune the validation with the pattern attribute
    `<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+">`

Comment: Thanks for the links, I can see where those are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are few minor issues in the code.
ID values are wrongly provided in your JS code

Eg: you have `fnameError` as ID to display error in firstname.

```
<span id="fnameError" style="display: none;">You can only use alphabetic characters, hyphens and apostrophes</span>
```

Whereas in the Javascript, you have used just `nameError`

```
document.getElementById('nameError').style.display = "block";
```

Similar kind of spelling issue is there in lastname also.. fix if there is anymore reference issues because of spelling differences, then you are good to go.